# Import CSV Data using APIs in MS Dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365-sales

I am trying to load bulk amount of CSV data into MS Dynamics using APIs. I can see API which can load JSON data into MS Dynamics object but nothing for CSV input. Is there any API which loads CSV data into MS Dynamics object?